# POO em Java - Modelagem Copa do Mundo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos, uml

Estou adentrado ao universo de Orientação à Objetos e, movido pela curiosidade, decidi tentar simular a organização de uma Copa do Mundo através destes conceitos.

Bom, estou com algumas dificuldades com relação às classes e gostaria da ajuda de vocês para que, através da análise da Modelagem abaixo, pudessem me orientar.

[image: ModelagemCopa - Lucidchart]

Comment: Você já tentou implementar?

Answer (score 0):

Um grupo contém seleções e não o contrário, então a composição deveria estar "invertida".

Um grupo também contém partidas, então está faltando uma agregação.

No mais, acho que você aplicou bem os conceitos.

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, porém acredito que dessa forma, não há relacionamento entre "Grupo" e "Partida" ao fim da Fase de Grupos. Por isso que considerei que uma Seleção disputa uma Partida pois, assim, as seleções classificadas continuam com o mesmo critério de partida.

Comment: Você pode fazer uma interface de partida e então implementá-la na fase de grupos, playoffs, semi-finais e tal também.